# Get string between two regex matches

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a regex string pattern for a Java function to process tweets. After much cleaning, now my data format is: "tweet;device;tweet;device..."

The example data format is as below,

> RT @blah1: blahbla;some device1 RT @blah2: blabla;some dev2 @blah3:
>   blahblah;some dev3

Problems:

I want to get the string between "RT @blah1:" and ";some device" iteratively.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The String class offers many ways to manipulate Strings. 
In this case you could use the split()-method:
split by ; and then split by :

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "RT @blah1: blahbla;some device1 RT @blah2: blabla;some dev2 @blah3: blahblah;some dev3";

    for (String part : s.split(";")) {
        if (part.contains(":")) {
            System.out.println(part.split(":")[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

If : and ; are not good enough to split you could replace them in split() by some regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment of the answers above, i.e. use string.split() first.

If you insist on using REGEX, use the following:

```
(?:^[^@]+@[^:]+:\s)([^;]+)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/cOmKhU/1

Explanation:

- (?:^[^@]+@[^:]+:\s) -> Non capturing Group, starting at the beginning of the line with more than 1 non-@, followed by @, more than one non-: and 1 whitespace
- ([^;]+) -> capturing Group, all characters (except for :) until the next :